# $setIntersection for new set of array to be searched return count matched

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

For movies released in the USA with a tomatoes.viewer.rating greater than or equal to 3, calculate a new field called num_favs that represets how many favorites appear in the cast field of the movie.

Iam not sure how to proceed further can you please help

```
 favorites = 
    ["Sandra Bullock",
    "Tom Hanks",
    "Julia Roberts",
    "Kevin Spacey",
    "George Clooney"]

     db.movies.aggregate([
   { $match:{
     'tomatoes.viewer.rating':{$gte:3},
     "countries":"USA"
         }
    }
    ]).
```

Answer (score 5):

```
var favorites =  [
  "Sandra Bullock",
  "Tom Hanks",
  "Julia Roberts",
  "Kevin Spacey",
  "George Clooney"]


db.movies.aggregate([
    {
        $match: 
        {
            "tomatoes.viewer.rating": { $gte:3 },
            "cast": 
            { 
                $in:["Sandra Bullock","Tom Hanks","Julia Roberts","Kevin Spacey","George Clooney"]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            _id:0,
            "tomatoes.viewer.rating":1,
            title:1,
            cast:1,
            num_favs:
                {
                    $size:
                    {
                        $setIntersection:["$cast",favorites]
                    }
                }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:
        {
            "num_favs":-1,
            "tomatoes.viewer.rating":-1,
            title:-1
        }
    }
    ])
```

I Think This will probably get you the correct answer. What I found was that if you don't match the cast then you get blank or null in num_favs but if you $match the cast, then you get the proper answer. Please let me know if there are any changes. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my pipeline for this problem

```
[
 {$match: {
 countries: 'USA',
 'tomatoes.viewer.rating': {
  $gte: 3
 },
 cast: {
  $type: 'array'
 }
}},

 {$project: {
 title: 1,
 'tomatoes.viewer.rating': 1,
 num_favs: {
  $size: {
   $setIntersection: [
    '$cast',
    [
     'Sandra Bullock',
     'Tom Hanks',
     'Julia Roberts',
     'Kevin Spacey',
     'George Clooney'
    ]
   ]
  }
 }
}}, 

{
$sort: {
 num_favs: -1,
 'tomatoes.viewer.rating': -1,
 title: -1
}}, 

{$skip: 24}]
```